# What is wrong with my method isReverse

Tags: java, recursion

Write a recursive method called isReverse("word1", "word2") that accepts two Strings as parameters and returns true if the two Strings contain
the same sequence of characters as each other but in opposite order, ignoring case, and returning false otherwise. 
For example, the call of:

```
isReverse("Desserts", "Stressed")
```

would return true. [So eat desserts when you are stressed?]
Null, empty and one letter strings are also to return true (if both parameters are the same value).
This is homework and I am having trouble making this code work appropriately. It returns true no matter what I do.

```
public static boolean isReverse(String word1, String word2) 
{
    if(word1 == null || word2 == null)
    {
        if(word1!= null && word2 != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else if(word1.length() == word2.length())
    {
        String firstWord = word1.substring(0, word1.length());
        String secondWord = word2.substring(word2.length()-1);
        if (firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase(secondWord))
        { 
            return isReverse(word1.substring(0, word1.length()), word2.substring(word2.length() - 1));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: String or StringBuffer class has a reverse method

Comment: @SrinathGanesh - StringBuilder has reverse, but we have to assume that he hasn't been taught about the Builder class. I've gone through 3 years of college without it being mentioned.

Comment: Given that this is homework, I'd guess that using a built-in function to complete 95% of the assignment is off-limits.

Comment: Your secondWord has just 1 character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this an exercise? Recursion doesn't seems to be the best option here. Anyway, you're just trimming one word, why? You must trim both words if you expect to compare each char in each recursive call. And you're not even passing the trimmed words as parameter to the recursive function!

The basic thing you're missing is a base case. When the recursion must return? In your case, you're reducing each string size at each step of recursion, so you must have a base case to check if the size is one.

Hope that this code clear your mind:

```
public static boolean isReverse(String word1, String word2) {
    if (word1 == null || word2 == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (word1.length() == 1 && word2.length() == 1) {
        //Used equals just for fast compare
        return word1.equals(word2);
    } else if (word1.length() == word2.length()) {
        if (word1.charAt(0) == word2.charAt(word2.length() - 1)) {
            String firstWord = word1.substring(1, word1.length());
            String secondWord = word2.substring(0, word2.length() - 1);
            System.out.printf("Trimmed %s, %s to %s, %s\n", word1, word2, firstWord, secondWord);
            return isReverse(firstWord, secondWord);
        } else {
            //Characters didn't matched
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        //Lenght doesn't match
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have this set so that it will only return false if both words are null; If they are not null you're re-calling the method(in the event that the length is equal), which will return true.

```
private static boolean isReverse(String a, String b) {
    // make sure the strings are not null
    if(a == null || b == null) return false;

    // If the lengths are not equal, the strings cannot be reversed.
    if(a.length() != b.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Convert string b to an array;
    char[] bArray = b.toCharArray();

    // Create an array to write bArray into in reverse.
    char[] copy = new char[bArray.length];

    // Iterate through bArray in reverse and write to copy[]
    for(int i = bArray.length; i < 0; i--) {
        copy[bArray.length - i] = bArray[i];
    }

    // Convert copy[] back into a string.
    String check = String.valueOf(copy);

    // See if they reversed string is equal to the original string.
    if(check.equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

```
    if (firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase(secondWord))
    { 
        return isReverse(word1.substring(0, word1.length()), word2.substring(word2.length() - 1));
    }
```

which is OK. But what if firstWord does not equal second word

It falls through and returns true.

You need to add an

```
else
    return false;
```

I will also add that your null checking will not work.

```
    if(word1!= null && word2 != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Is not useful because you are already in an if that only happens when word1 or word2 is null. So they can't be null and null here.

It would work if you made it

```
    if(word1 == null && word2 == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I have reversed one of the string(i took word1) using recursion.then compared to second string if both strings are equal result set to true.

```
public static boolean isReverse(String word1, String word2)
{
    boolean result  = false;
    //check null to avoid null pointer exception
    if(word1 == null | word2 == null){
        result = false;
    }else if(word1.length() == word2.length()){

         word1 = reverseString(word1);
         if(word1.equalsIgnoreCase(word2)){
             result = true;
         }
    }
    return result;

}   

static String reverse = "";
public static String reverseString(String str){

    if(str.length() == 1){
        reverse+=str;

    } else {
        reverse += str.charAt(str.length()-1)
                +reverseString(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Can  you explain what you have done here? Code-only answers tend not to be very explanatory.